# Jtable cellRenderer change background of row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cellrenderer

I have been tryng for some time and looking over the internet to find the solution however I have failed.
What I'm trying to do is to change row background of Jtable dynamically.
I have created arrayList which keeps numbers of selected rows (Adding them everytime user press alt+click on a cell)
and in my own tableCellRenderer I have added

```
for(Integer c: leftSelectedCells){
if(c.equals(row)){comp.setForeground(Color.red); }
else { comp.setForeground(Color.black);}
}
```

It is working, for few cells, or some time after which selected columns are back to their oryginal color, I have checked, the ints are still in Array so thats not the problem, any idea what might cause the issue?

Comment: You're gong to need to supply TableCellRenderes for each column type that is capable of providing the functionality you require. Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Just a general recommendation, but usually CTRL (not ALT) is the modifier key used for multi-select.

Comment: In this case, it might be preferable to use JTable.setDefaultCellRenderer instead of setting renderers by column. Also: you say you want to change the row background, but your sample code instead sets the foreground.  In my answer, I've followed your lead in setting the foreground, but you could easily modify it to set the background instead if, indeed, that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested in comments above, you need to provide a custom renderer for all required columns. As an alternative, you can override `JTable.prepareRenderer` to set the background according to the list of affected rows. [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) by @camickr explains this approach. Below is an example that highlights rows clicked with mouse + <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. For simplicity, the list of highlighted rows is kept as client property.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableHighlight {
    TableHighlight() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableHighlight");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object[][] data = { { "Column 1", "Column 2" },
                { "Column 1", "Column 2" }, { "Column 1", "Column 2" },
                { "Column 1", "Column 2" } };

        Object[] columnNames = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        final JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                    int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                List<Integer> selectedRows = (List<Integer>) getClientProperty("highlightRows");
                c.setBackground(selectedRows.contains(row) ? Color.cyan : getBackground());
                return c;
            }
        };

        table.putClientProperty("highlightRows", new ArrayList<Integer>());

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (!evt.isAltDown())
                    return;
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                if (row == -1)
                    return;
                List<Integer> selectedRows = (List<Integer>) table
                        .getClientProperty("highlightRows");
                int index = selectedRows.indexOf(row);
                if (index != -1)
                    selectedRows.remove(index);
                else
                    selectedRows.add(row);
                table.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableHighlight();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using CTRL for multi-select instead of ALT.  For one, any users who want to multi-select will already know how to do it because CTRL is the de-facto standard modifier key for multi-select.  Second, you get the behavior you want for free, without having to implement anything special (except, perhaps, your preferred color scheme).

```
package com.example.table.multiselect;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class MultiRowTableSelect extends JFrame {

    public MultiRowTableSelect() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 3);
        model.addRow(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
        model.addRow(new Integer[]{4, 5, 6});
        model.addRow(new Integer[]{7, 8, 9});
        model.addRow(new Integer[]{10, 11, 12});

        JTable tbl = new JTable(model);
        tbl.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); // when you click a cell, the entire row will be highlighted

        /* Assuming you want all cells to be rendered using the custom renderer
         * unless otherwise overridden, you can simply set the JTable's default
         * renderer.  The implementation is so simple here that I'm just
         * creating an anonymous subclass of DefaultTableCellRenderer.
         */
        tbl.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                if (isSelected) {
                    c.setForeground(Color.RED); // you can set the foreground and/or background here
                }

                return c;
            }
        });

        add(new JScrollPane(tbl), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
        setSize(400, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultiRowTableSelect();
    }

}
```